# Google Maps SDK drop marker

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using Google Maps SDK in my Iphone app.
Now I want to drop marker when user touch and hold on map more than 2 sec on touched place, but I can't find any solution.

Thank you...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found solution.

You should implement **GMSMapViewDelegate** protocol on the view controller that displays the map and listen to didLongPressAtCoordinate event.

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

and

```
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
GMSMarker *marker3 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker3.position = coordinate;
marker3.title = @"170 Asbury Anderson Rd";
marker3.snippet = @"US";
marker3.map = mapView_;
}
```

[Protocol GMS Map View Delegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#a0499f484d9ea51041babd3ac8dcc7b27)